# Spinner Title shows its Zero position element

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

I am using Spinner in one of my activity. Problem is that it shows its zero index element as title. because of this it appears twice, first in title and second is as first element of spinner. I don't want to give the selected option Which is in title in spinner drop down because its already selected So whats the use of it to give it as spinner first option. I want the selected option in title and rest of the option in Spinner list. Have a look at my code -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and adapter class is -

```
 public class SpinnerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context mContext;
List<SpinnerContent> list;
public SpinnerAdapter(Context context, List<SpinnerContent> list) {
    mContext = context;
    this.list = list;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    SpinnerContent item = list.get(position);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.spinner_item_row_image,
                null);
    }
    TextView tvTitle = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.tvSpinnerItem);
    ImageView imgSpinnerContent = (ImageView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.imgSpinnerItem);
    if (item.getCollectionName().equalsIgnoreCase("Home")) {
        imgSpinnerContent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        imgSpinnerContent.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_home);
        tvTitle.setText("Home");
        tvTitle.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(
                R.color.white_text));
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(
                R.color.text_color_light_gray));
    } else if (item.getCollectionName().equalsIgnoreCase("One Level Up")) {
        imgSpinnerContent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        imgSpinnerContent.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_spinner_up);
        tvTitle.setText("One Level Up");
        tvTitle.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(
                R.color.white_text));
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(
                R.color.text_color_light_gray));
    } else if (item.getCollectionName().equalsIgnoreCase("One Level Down")) {
        imgSpinnerContent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        imgSpinnerContent.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_spinner_down);
        tvTitle.setText("One Level Down");
        tvTitle.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(
                R.color.white_text));
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(
                R.color.text_color_light_gray));
    } else {
        if (position == 0) {
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources()
                    .getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
            imgSpinnerContent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tvTitle.setText(item.getCollectionName());
            tvTitle.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(
                    R.color.white_text));
        } else {
            tvTitle.setText(item.getCollectionName());
            applyTheme(convertView, mContext);
        }
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

How can I achieve it. I want first element of list (Which is passed to spinner) as title but don't want to show it as first element of spinner. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you have to use Spinner prompt attribute for title instead option list include title.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible with spinner. Spinner always shows the first element as title. If you want to add title then you better display your title at 0th position. In validation part if user selects 0th position set validation message to user.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use Kevin Chris solution.

Still if you want to achieve then try following trick.I never used this but it should work.

```
spinner.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            View convertView = spinner.getSelectedView();
            View selectedView= adapter.getDropDownView(selectedPosition, convertView, spinner);
            selectedView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```